# normalized_mutual_info_score in sklearn giving negative values or values greater than 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to calculate the normalized mutual information between two 256*256 image labels, flatten into an array.

In sklearn's documentation it was clear that the function normalized_mutual_info_score should only output values between 0 and 1.

However I realise that when comparing lists with lots of elements sometimes it gives me negative values or values larger than 1.

Is it an overflow/underflow problem? (I realise that I got a more realistic answer if I change average_method to "arithmetic", "min", or "max" but not sure which one would be the most appropriate to use in my case.)

Using sklearn 0.20.0, I'll provide a synthetic example to reproduce the problem:

```
metrics.normalized_mutual_info_score([0]*100001, [0]*100000 + [1])
metrics.normalized_mutual_info_score([0]*110001, [0]*110000 + [1])
```

I expect the answer below to be 0 but instead I got 7.999 and -7.999 respectively.

Comment: When I use 'geometric' instead of 'arithmetic' I still get negative values or values above 1. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned that setting the average_method gives sensible values.

```
normalized_mutual_info_score([0]*100001, [0]*100000 + [1],average_method='arithmetic')
#3.166757680223739e-14
```

I would suggest using the `arithmetic` since that it going to be the default value in next version 0.22, [reference](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/metrics/cluster/supervised.py#L798).